# Visual Studio Mac doesn't support List<string> function?

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, list

I'm attempting to create a List of variables in C# on VS Mac preview. I know its unstable, but It's what i have right now.

The code isn't anything crazy, here's what I've tried:

```
List<string> Characters = new List<string>(new string[] { "Char1", "Char2", "Char3" });
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong - error is "The Type or Namespace "List" could not be found". I can't even get it to pass in values from another public class, like `Public List<Directors>;`.

Very strange. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to include the namespace.

Comment: Here's the namespaces I have:

    `using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;`

Comment: It seems to be working now (sort of) but I'm still having issues with passing in values from other classes.

Comment: I have all but given up on the Mac version until they can stabilize it.

Comment: Honestly same, but its finals week and my Dell with a Pentium CPU just aint cutting it. going to have to double check everything when I'm at the lab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the namespace

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

This is the library where List is defined. If it's not there the compiler doesn't know what List refers to

Comment: is there a namespace for class inheritance  that I'm missing?

Comment: still unable to pass things from another class into a list.

Comment: @Nick Could you please edit your initial question with the code you are having trouble with, I can help as best I can but I need more information. Elaborate a little here as well, do you mean you can't instantiate a list with a non primitive data type? (for example, you create a class called Test and try to create a List of type <Test>)

Comment: I'm going to try and work through it - if I really get stuck I might update the question and ping you (if you're available of course). thanks for the help!

Comment: @Nick No problem! Good luck with your issue.

Comment: And yes - thats exactly what I mean - I want to instantiate a list from a class that has some inherited fields and such.

Comment: @Nick Keep trying and if you still can't find the problem post your source code and I'll help.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you include the namespace for the `List<T>` type:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```